# how i can protect my internet connection from being spoofed?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

(I'm a new Ubuntu user)is it possible that someone on the same network can cut my Internet connection ? is there anyway to protect it from being "spoofed" ? how can i identify who tried to do that ? Thanks !

Comment: Security is a broad topic and your question is, IMO, very broad.

Comment: Sorry  i didn't understand your answer. can you put more details ?

Comment: Although this is a broad topic, it is a frequently asked question (on other forums and irc, etc) which makes me believe completely deleting the question will only create a void tempting another user to create such a question.

Answer (score 1):

You must trust your LAN.  There are many nefarious things that can be done and your question is very broad.

If you're in need of a simple, secure solution, you can create an SSH Tunnel between your computer and a trusted host, but again, you've got to trust that host's LAN.

Comment: thanks .i understand It is possible to get spoofed buy someone on the same network . what can i need to build a "SSH Tunnel"

Comment: Client (your computer), Host (computer on a remote network), Google  "SSH Tunnel".  HINT: `ssh -fND 12345 host`